# Change data detection in REST API

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, etl, delta

I'm building an ETL process that extracts data from REST API and then pushes the update messages to queue. The API doesn't support delta detection and uses hard delete for data deletion (record just disappears). I currently detect changes by keeping the table in DynamoDB that contains all the record ids along with their CRC. Whenever the API data is extracted next time I compare every record's CRC towards a CRC stored in DynamoDB thus detecting if change has occurred.

This allows to detect the updates/inserts but wouldn't detect the deletions. Is there a best practice of how to detect hard deletes without putting the whole dataset into memory?

I'm currently thinking of this:
1. Have a Redis/DynamoDB table where the last extracted data snapshot would be temporarily saved
2. When the data extraction is complete - do the reverse processing - stream the data from DynamoDB comparing against Redis dataset to detect the missing key values

Is there a best practice / better approach with regard to this?

Comment: I have done this in the past by keeping all the *hashes* (e.g. SHA1 of each row) of the complete data set in memory... but that was using an RDBMS that could calculate those for me and return a set of roe hashes.  It doesn't seem a likely fit with DynamoDB.  Touching each record with a timestamp or some other "sync token" is another tactic, since every row with an old value is now missing... but that breaks down again with DynamoDB, because it requires writes that are otherwise unnecessary.  Intetesting question.